# Call shapefile from a folder and extract each x,y coordinate system

Tags: python, geopandas, numpy, globe

I am curious about the script that calls multiple shapefiles from a folder and extracts each x,y coordinate system.

(I have completed calling the shapefile from the folder so far.)

```
import glob
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd

files = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\clip\*.shp')
gdfs = (gpd.read_file(file) for file in files)
```

Pictures for the x,y coordinate system in the above article.

[image]

Comment: Can you please give an example of *"an x,y coordinate system"*?

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your reply.
Added explanations and pictures for the x,y coordinate system in the above article.

Answer (score 1):

Use [.crs](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.crs.html), and/or list the fields holding the attributes you want to print out:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import os

fields = ["EASTING","NORTHING", "MGRS"]
for root, folder, files in os.walk(r'C:\GIS\data\tempdata'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".shp"):
            df = gpd.read_file(os.path.join(root, file))
            print(df.crs)
            print(df[fields])
```

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your reply.How to extract to excel file?

Comment: [pandas.DataFrame.to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html#pandas-dataframe-to-excel)